# ¿Por qué mi DatePicker no escucha los cambios de fecha?

Tags: android, datepicker

Tengo este DatePicker, pero no escucha los cambios de fecha.

Mi idea es lanzar un Menú contextual cuando el usuario haga click en cualquier fecha, pero ni siquiera me escucha los cambios.

#### XML

```
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleX="1.0"
        android:scaleY="1.0"/>
```

#### Fragmento

```
    DatePicker datePicker = binding.datePicker;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Log.d("Date", "Year=" + year + " Month=" + (month + 1) + " day=" + dayOfMonth);

        }
    });
```

Se supone que debería ver el Log cuando la fecha cambie, pero no ocurre.

Comment: ¿Y qué imprime el log?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo no imprime nada, no entra en ese bloque de código.

Comment: ¿Cómo que no? Lo acabo de probar y pues a mi me ha funcionado bien. Me ha mostrado lo siguiente en la consola `2021-12-13 13:08:13.543 32143-32143/com.example.myapplication D/Date: Year=2021 Month=12 day=14` ¿Cómo creaste tu proyecto?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo parece que en el Fragment donde lo estaba probando habría otro código que interfería o algo, pues lo he probado en un Fragmento nuevo y funciona. Gracias.

Comment: ¡Que bueno que se haya solucionado!